# Matrix $A$ with $A^{3}=I$ and Canonical Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $A \in M_{2}(\mathbb{Q})$ be a matrix which satisfies $A^{3}=I$, for $I$ being the identity matrix and $A$ different from $I$. Express $A$ in rational canonical form and in Jordan form as a matrix in $\mathbb{C}$.

---

What would be a way to get started with this problem? I know that for the minimum polynomial of $A$, then one has $m_{A}(x)|x^{3}-1$ (as the minimum polynomial divides any other polynomial that makes $A$ vanish), and this polynomial factors into distinct factors in $\mathbb{C}$ (I think).

How could one use this information to write both canonical forms for a matrix satisfying this property? Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Good start. Can you factor $p(x) = x^3 - 1$? One of the factors must be the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^{3}-1=(x-1)(x^{2}+x+1)$, is the factorisation over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. $m_{A}(x)$ has to divide $x^{3}-1$ and has degree at most $2$. Now, since $A$ is not the indentity, the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^{2}+x+1$. Now, you can factor $x^{2}+x+1$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I see. Thus the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ will be $x^{2}+x+1$ and thus it will be the only invariant factor, giving us an easy way to compute the rational canonical form. Otherwise, for the Jordan form, since the factors are distinct, would it just be a diagonal matrix with the roots along it?

Answer (score 1):

$$m_A(x) \mid x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

The latter is the irreducible factorization of $x^3-1$ over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Since $A$ is $2 \times 2$ matrix, then $\deg m_A (x) \le 2$ by Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. Therefore, $m_A(x) = x-1$ or $m_A(x) =  x^2 + x + 1$. The former would imply $A = I$ which by assumption cannot be, so the latter must be true. Then since the minimal polynomial is already degree 2, this completely determines the rational canonical form.

Over $\mathbf{C}$, which is algebraically closed, $x^3 - 1$ splits. Namely, if $\zeta_3$ is a primitive root of unity, then  $$x^3 - 1 = (x - \zeta _ 3) (x - \zeta_3 ^2 ) (x-1)$$

In this form, it is clear that $x^3 - 1$ has no repeated roots and so the minimal polynomial also cannot have repeated roots. This is equivalent to saying that the Jordan Canonical Form is actually a diagonal matrix with such a minimal polynomial. Then its third power must be zero so all of its entries must be third roots of unity.